# Proof for constant function without Picard's little theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove **without using Picard's Little Theorem** the following statement:

Let $f(z)$ an entire function such that $f(z) \notin \mathbb R$  for every $z \in \mathbb C$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Do you have a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know about the maximum principle for the real and imaginary parts of a harmonic function?  Or Liouville's theorem and the Cauchy Riemann equations?

Answer (score 7):

Hint : The hypothesis implies that $Im f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, so
$$\mathbb{C}=\{Im f(z)>0\} \cup \{Im f(z) < 0\}.$$

Use the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is connected to deduce that either $Im f(z)<0$ for all $z$ for $Im f(z)>0$ or all $z$. Then, apply Liouville's theorem to either $g(z):=e^{if(z)}$ or $g(z):=e^{-if(z)}$.

Comment: Or $g(z):=1/(i+f)$ or $g(z):=1/(f-i)$.

Comment: Yes indeed, good idea. Thank you for the comment.